# How do I get the dynamic width of an unordered list with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, list, width

I am writing a plugin that transforms standard form element markup into more customizable markup.  My select menus are transformed into unordered lists.  I have a division above the list that shows what option(list item) is selected.  The width of the UL is relative to the longest text.  I want to change the width of the "selected option" division to match the width of the UL.  In chrome's dev console, it shows that the UL is a little over 103px wide.  When I log the width of the UL in console, it shows as 1,800 something(my screen res is 1920 by 1080, so I'm guessing it has to do with that).  How can I get the dynamic width of an unordered list?

The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShoeLace1291/7yL233kb/1)

Note that I indicate where the css files begin in that pane in the jsFiddle.

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jqForminator Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqforminator.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jqForminator Demo</h1>
<p>The jqForminator jQuery plugin transforms the standard form element markup into more customizable markup.</p>

<form action="" id="forminator">
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Select Menu</label><br>
        <select name="selection">
            <option value="1">First Option</option>
            <option value="2">Second Option</option>
            <option value="3" SELECTED>Third Option</option>
            <option value="4">Fourth Option</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Checkboxes</label>
        <ul class="horizontal-list">
            <li>Apples <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="1"></li>
            <li>Bananas <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="2"></li>
            <li>Oranges <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="3"></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <label>Radio Buttons</label>
        <ul class="horizontal-list">
            <li>Pizza <input type="radio" name="radios" value="1"></li>
            <li>Tacos <input type="radio" name="radios" value="2"></li>
            <li>Spaghetti <input type="radio" name="radios" value="3"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#forminator').jqForminator({
            select_menus : true,
            checkboxes : true,
            radio_buttons : true,
            css_path : 'css'
        });
    });
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

[image]

Apparently, this works in jsFiddle, but not on my HTML page... very puzzled.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML (assuming that's what the picture of the Web Inspector was for?) in your question. *Ideally* a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo is useful to reproduce your current situation and problem. Do, however, post *only the minimal* [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) code,  not *all* your code.

Comment: I edited the question to include a jsFiddle link as well as the HTML code instead of the jQuery since that's in the jsFiddle.